# App is installed twice

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have a shoppinglist App coded in Android-Studios. My app does have a splash screen. When I install the app, it is installed twice. When I uninstall one, the other one uninstalls too. I tried to delete the first intent filter on splashscreen, but then I did not have a splash screen anymore. I want my splashscreen to be remain. How to solve that? My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.projects.buylist">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The app is **only one**.

You have simply two activities (and then 2 icons) that can work as launcher.

If you don't want, you have to remove this part in one Activity

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: or instead of removing , you can make it `DEFAULT` instead of `LAUNCHER` and use activity name in place of `MAIN` to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 2):

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` this is telling android you want the activity to be visible from the app launcher. To solve it, remove the `intent-filter` from `MainActivity`.

Comment: Thank you, I understood the problem now.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your main intent in XML and create something like this, which will run splashscreen and then open your MainActivity

```
public class SplashsScreen extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashsScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                SplashsScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashsScreen.this.finish();
            }
        }, 1500); // 1500 ms = 1.5 s
   }
}
```

Comment: This will also allow you to check for permissions if you have to before launching the main application

Comment: Thank you very much. Where can I see this permissions allowing? Could you be a bit more accurate please?

Comment: Well you would add your permissions in XML first, above the `<application>` tag, for example `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`, which would use internet permission and then have something like this in code above `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        1);`

Comment: Wow, I did not know this, thank you very much. I will keep this in mind!